# Missing _va_list.h header file in XCode

Tags: c, xcode

Using Xcode command line tools, when attempting to compile a C file that includes stdio.h, the compiler is producing the following error:

```
/usr/include/stdio.h:71:10: fatal error: 'sys/_types/_va_list.h' file not found
#include <sys/_types/_va_list.h>
```

The compiler info is

```
LSK-Macbook-Pro:sys larry$ gcc --version
Configured with: --prefix=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr --with-gxx-include-dir=/usr/include/c++/4.2.1
Apple LLVM version 5.1 (clang-503.0.40) (based on LLVM 3.4svn)
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin13.2.0
Thread model: posix
```

How can I this this file back so I can use the compiler?

Comment: I would suggest reinstalling the command line tools. If you're missing this file then it indicates that you've had something go wrong on your install.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, Petesh. That solved the problem. Evidently, the initial installation failed to finish and I didn't notice at the time.